# showing image of sixe 64 X 64 on any size imageview without loosing its quality

Tags: android, image

I am retrieving image from server and setting it to image view.The image size is 64 X 64 .
But I want it to suppport all size image views. If I use imageview of size 150dp X 150dp
it gets blurred out,it stretches.Is there any method so that my image maintains its quality even on bigger size imageview?I had heard to use ninepatch images in drawable but here i'm downloading it from server and image size is fixed 64 X 64 .

Plz Help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

NinePatch is for stretching images, usually only for background images with a single color or a gradient in one direction. So that is not your answer.

As to showing your 64x64 image as 150x150.. no. It's just as if you'd do image enlargement in an image editor - the information is not there. Although it shouldn't be that bad.

Check this to see if any alternative fits your needs:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Typically used:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image1"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"          
   />
```

Comment: but is there any way as i've to show the same image on tab as well as cell phones?

Comment: Tablets might as well have LOWER resolution than phones. 64px pics are quite small, you will in any situation with that resolution be hard pressed to perform perfect when upscaling. All that said: Android is not bad at scaling up.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid it can't be done...Not with all image types at least. There are images called VECTOR images which retains quality at significant level of image resizes. So you should try using some vector kinda images which could be of .PNG images, etc.

Because shrinking a larger image works most of the time, but enlarging smaller images will always under distortion.